# Can we assign all RGB color combination color as html body background and set the color of a particular section dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question may be strange but just want to know the probability of achieving this,

I have an image with all combination of (0,0,0) to (255,255,255)

[image]

It is easy to use this as background for html body.

> But Instead of using an image, Is it possible to fill a body
>   background-color using CSS color property just similar to image?

Hope you understand my question?

**UPDATE:**

Can we get the color property of a particular section of the page.
I mean, I want to get the color of the area that is 3px from top position. So that i cab assign it to another div dynamically.

> Suppose i have a fixed header, and i keep on scrolling the content of
>   the page. Then how can i change the color of the header dynamically
>   that is equal to the top 2px section that is being scrolled.

Comment: I want to change the color of the menu's dynamically that reside on the web page. so if user scrolls to some extent i would like to change the color of the menu's  that matches to the color of the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use CSS gradients. You can generate them automatically with online tools like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

I created one for you that is shnazzy:
http://jsfiddle.net/3nC9V/

The CSS

```css
#cool {
    height:1000px;

    background: #ffb76b; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%, #ff0509 10%, #ff6b6b 22%, #fff76b 36%, #2aff00 52%, #6bfff5 65%, #6b6dff 80%, #ff05ea 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffb76b), color-stop(10%,#ff0509), color-stop(22%,#ff6b6b), color-stop(36%,#fff76b), color-stop(52%,#2aff00), color-stop(65%,#6bfff5), color-stop(80%,#6b6dff), color-stop(100%,#ff05ea)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ff0509 10%,#ff6b6b 22%,#fff76b 36%,#2aff00 52%,#6bfff5 65%,#6b6dff 80%,#ff05ea 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ff0509 10%,#ff6b6b 22%,#fff76b 36%,#2aff00 52%,#6bfff5 65%,#6b6dff 80%,#ff05ea 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ff0509 10%,#ff6b6b 22%,#fff76b 36%,#2aff00 52%,#6bfff5 65%,#6b6dff 80%,#ff05ea 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffb76b 0%,#ff0509 10%,#ff6b6b 22%,#fff76b 36%,#2aff00 52%,#6bfff5 65%,#6b6dff 80%,#ff05ea 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb76b', endColorstr='#ff05ea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="cool">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The general term for this is a gradient.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

You may not be able to get every colour as they only allow linear gradients (although by chaining divs together you possibly could).